# Local DC/OS is unreachable

Tags: virtualbox, mesos, dcos

I have a DC/OS local installation using vagrant. I have restarted my Mac machine and power up the virtual machines on which dc/os is installed. Still I not not able to open the GUI. When I give docs service command on CLI, I get the following error

URL [http://m1.dcos/mesos/master/state.json] is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

The response I got from mesosphere:

It would be good if you can login to your master node with:
vagrant
 ssh m1

And run the following command:
sudo
 systemctl status dcos-adminrouter.service

I have cleaned up the vagrant environment and set up again. I am not facing the problem yet.